# Does ABRecordGetRecordID changes value when something changed in contact info?

Tags: addressbook

I want to sync my custom address book with ABAddressBookRef and I am wandering if ABRecordGetRecordID is changing value when user changes something in contact info. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, the recordID does not change when the user changes contact info.  However, the recordID is not 'permanent'.  It is not guaranteed to be consistent across devices, so it is possible for the recordID to change out from under you.  This is covered in the [Address Book Programming Guide in the Direct Interaction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1) section